# How Do I Disable a VBA Sub Using Another Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is designed to essentially operate as a standalone application. All sheets are protected, the individual excel tabs are hidden, and the top excel ribbon is hidden as well for the entire workbook.

The following VBA code performs the above procedures and is applied to every sheet within the workbook.

```
Sub masque()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I want to use the following code as a button to override the prior code in order for an individual to easily switch between an "editor" mode and "user mode"

```
Sub masteredit()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayHorizontalScrollBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayVerticalScrollBar = True
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True
Application.DisplayFullScreen = False
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

What is a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: you should really look into the `with` keyword. it'd make this look so much nicer

Comment: does this code already swap from 'editor' to 'user' modes and you just want to know how to call them, or is there an error somewhere?

Comment: Add a button and assign the macro.  Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

well, you could have a predermined type of user, for example, by default the app will be for user_mode. So you use a special sub called auto_open(), that will be run each time you open the workbook. So we have

```
sub auto_open()
call masque
end sub
```

And you can add buttons whenever you want to change between editor mode and user mode. You can put sub auto_open() in any module you want, because it is detected as special by Vba

Answer (score 0):

**Solved the issue.**

I forgot I had the following code on every sheet in the workbook.

```
Sub Worksheet_Open()
Call masque
End Sub
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call masque
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Therefore, any time I tried to navigate to a different sheet, the masque would be applied.

To solve my issue, I removed the prior code from every page. I then added a checkbox on my "Home" page that used the following code.

```
Sub Worksheet_Open()
Call masque
End Sub
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call masque
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This way, when you open up the workbook the masque is automatically applied. However when you click the checkbox you enter editor mode and the masteredit sub is applied. And when it is unchecked, the masque is once again applied.